# ruby custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am new to ruby on rails.

Here is my routes.rb

```
RpxNowExample::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => "users#index"
  resources :users
end
```

Normally my functionality is working fine, but I want to make a tweak. I want it to redirect to another view "promptemail" using the same controller calling another action if a condition is true i.e

```
if(@provider == "Twitter")

     redirect_to :action => :promptemail

end
```

It should take me to that `promptemail` view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a block to your resources definition to add extra actions outside of the standard:

```
resources :users do
  match :promptemail, :via => [:get], :on => :member
end
```

The `:via` option allows you to restrict on get, post, put etc, the `:on` parameter will take either :member, or :collection.

`:collection` will operate on a collection, so similar to the index action, `:member` will operate on an individual record. As such if you specify your route as `:on => :member`, you will need to provide an object or id when you generate the route.

More info about adding routes to resources can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: it pops up **No route matches {:action=>"promptemail", :controller=>"users"}**

Comment: In that case change `:on => :member` to `:on => :collection`

Comment: on this promptemail view can i submit the form back to the index calling 'create' action ?

Comment: You can call any url helper just as you normally would.

Comment: i have this code in my promptemail view

<form action="/users/create" method = "post">
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <input type = "submit" /> 
 </form>

it pops up 

No route matches "/users/create"

Comment: oh got it. in that link you provided. siply sent post request on /users it automaticalled create method this time.
mmmmmmmmmuah love you :P

Comment: Marvellous, glad you got it sorted! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the same controller calling another action-

Try:

**routes.rb:**

```
RpxNowExample::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => "users#index"
  resources :users do
     collection do
        get 'promptemail'
      end
```

**Your controller:**

```
if(@provider == "Twitter")

     redirect_to :promptemail

end
```

**Note:**  - No need to call `action` in `redirect_to` as you are calling the action within the same controller.